# Auto attach to gnu screen on remote host (ssh) only

Tags: gnu-screen, zshrc

So I distribute my dotfiles on all my machines.  I want to put something like the following in my .zshrc

```
# Autoload screen if we aren't in it.
if [[ $STY = '' ]] then screen -xR; fi
```

Which I got from [What's in your .zshrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171563/whats-in-your-zshrc)

But I only want to attach to screen when I ssh to remote hosts... not if I'm on my local machine.  Is there an environment variable I can test to see if this is an SSH session or localhost console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now I'm going to test the $SSH_TTY variable which seems to be reliable from the few hosts I've tried:

```
if [[ $STY = '' && $SSH_TTY != '' ]] then screen -xR; fi
```